# Css conflict extended width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Having a hard time figuring out where and i need to use to avoid over extend of width to right causing the scroll to right appear and the height of the small images gets smaller. it should be 250px in height each to fit. Plus i need to add text in the bottom left of each image.

This is the picture for reference. [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMrQw.jpg)

HTML

```
<div class="news-banner">
<h1 class="text-center header-text">News</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 img-container">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/icons/people-crowd-child-kid-large.jpg"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 img-small">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/icons/13-Cuidados-alternativos-en-familia.jpg">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/icons/man-person-cute-young-large.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.news-banner {
height: 120px;
background: #eb1212;
position: relative;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.header-text{ 
color: white;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; 
}

.img-container {
height: 500px;
display: flex;
}

.img-small {
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a live demo, too?

Comment: i dont know where to put it sir so everyone can have a live experience.

Comment: Check your orginal image size first

Comment: @Brian we can not see that issue in fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/LaLukp6t/1/

Comment: @Hazard its fine its 250px in height but it not appears in the web.

Comment: @Brian wrote an answer it should work, as I got a working example here on my machine.

Comment: @Kordi can i take a look at it sir? i'm experimenting on width but no effect sad. haha

Comment: @Brian updated my Answer an on my machein with test images width=300 it works. On Firefox and Google Chrome!

Comment: @Brian let me know if my answer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for both the points

> It should be 250px in height each to fit.
>
> Plus I need to add text in the bottom left of each image.

Adding `img-wrapper` class to your div with class row, and with some additional css rules, Here is the demo. **View it in `Full Page` Mode**

```css
.news-banner {
  height: 120px;
  background: #eb1212;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
.header-text {
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.img-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.img-small {
  height: 100%;
}
.img-small div {
  height: 50%;
}
.img-small img {
  height: 100%;
}
.img-wrapper {
  height: 500px;
}
span.img-desc {
  color: white;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
.img-wrapper.row div[class|='col-md'] {
  padding: 0px;
}
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="news-banner">
  <h1 class="text-center header-text">News</h1>
</div>

<div class="row img-wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-8 img-container">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
    <span class="img-desc"> This Image Description </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 img-small">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg">
      <span class="img-desc"> This Image Description </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg">
      <span class="img-desc"> This Image Description </span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i extend the 2 images in the left closer to the right image?

Comment: That is default bootstrap padding between two columns, we can override it. Do you want to fix all the images exactly to each other or do you want a little gap between them?

Comment: @Brian I have updated my solution, check the demo now.

Comment: gonna check it sir wait.

Comment: i gonna add Subs text on the Decription thanks ! :D works perfectly

Comment: sir how can i add additional text i plan to make Title and sub text in the images.

Comment: Just extend the span tag with additional html to hold title and description, also you can pplce them accordingly using the `top,bottom,left,right` properties

Comment: follow up question sir. i think we dont have closing div for `row` and `img-wrapper`.

Comment: oh... I missed out that one, I fixed it. Thanks for letting me know this :)

Answer (score 0):

## Fix

Dont really know of the side effects of Bootstrap with your other code. But you can try this, too. It worked for me with Bootstrap.

```
html {
   width: 100%;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/bzLo33n8/ for the working example.

Comment: @Brian Ok I see it now. Have you a link to the 3 Images? And which Browser do you have?

Comment: Google Chrome. ok wait i will upload it wait for a while.

Comment: big image http://i65.tinypic.com/2m4ws9e.jpg small pics http://i68.tinypic.com/1196wap.jpg http://i63.tinypic.com/wlr53c.jpg

Comment: @Brian with the html class I updated my answer it really works. And don't forget to remove the other widht things. Added a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bzLo33n8/ where see how it works